# Javascript regex expression for underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a input field in GUI where user enters a text in textbox and clicks Save. I have to validate that text/string for below pattern.

```
String: "--cpuname=some_text" // Invalid string, underscore not allowed
String: "--cpuname=$(some_text)" // Valid string
String: "--cpuname=$(some_text) -order=abc_def" //Valid string
```

if cpuname value has underscore in it , then its not valid. But underscore is allowed if it is between `$(` and `)` like the second example above.   Note: `--cpuname` might not be starting of the string always and other part of text can have underscores.(except cpuname value)

Hope my requirement is clear.

The code I tried:

```
const regex = /--cpuname=[$(][^)]+\)|--cpuname=[^_]+(?:\s-\w+=\w+)*$/;

function checkStringValidity(str) {
  if (!regex.test(str)) {
    alert("Underscore not allowed");
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember to escape brackets with `\(` and `\)`. Underscores would not be a problem. Please post your attempt and what doesn't work. You can test on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or you can make a runnable snippet here with the `<>` button.

Comment: Please post your test case(s) with the code you tried to see what went wrong.

Comment: *with the code you tried* - classic

Comment: Why do you have `--hostname` in the regex if your strings have `--cpuname`? Also, if the whole string should match the pattern, you must use `^` at the start of the regex, but your 3rd example says that you should not have anchors.

Comment: It seems  to me that your positive regex (i.e. used with `if (!regex.test(str))`) is `/--cpuname=(?:\$\([^()]*\)|[^_])+(?!\S)/` or ``/--cpuname=(?:\$\([^()]*\)|[^_\s])+/``

Comment: sorry. edited the code i tried..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Given string can have anchors or direct value without anchors. But if underscore is present in between anchors $( and ) , then its valid. else report it is as not valid.  And this check should be done only for --cpuname=some_value.  Other part of text can have underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a different logic: create a regex that will match *invalid* `--cpuname` values and if there is a match, trigger an alert.

```js
const regex = /--cpuname=(?:\$\([^()]*\)|(?!\$\()[^_\s])*_/;

function checkStringValidity(str) {
  return regex.test(str);
}

const strs = ["--cpuname=some_text","--cpuname=$(some_text)", "--cpuname=$(some_text) -order=abc_def"];
for (const str of strs) {
  if (checkStringValidity(str)) {
    console.log("Underscore not allowed in cpuname value" + "\nThe '" + str + "' string is invalid!");
  } else {
    console.log("The '" + str + "' string is valid!");
  }
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vLvhTq/3).

*Details*:

- `--cpuname=` - a literal text
- `(?:\$\([^()]*\)|(?!\$\()[^_\s])*` - a non-capturing group that matches - 0 or more times - either of

  - `\$\([^()]*\)` - a `$(` + any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` + `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!\$\()[^_\s]` - a char other than `_` and whitespace that does not start a `$(` char sequence
- `_` - an underscore.

Comment: @Stunner Yes, please note I removed some unnecessary groupings to make the regex pattern c?leaner. I think your values in `cpuname` cannot contain `$(`, but if they can, you will need to replace `(?!\$\()` with `(?!\$\([^()]*\))`

Answer (score -1):

If the value has an underscore and it's not enclosed between $( and ), it's invalid.
If the value is enclosed between $( and ), underscores are allowed.
Let's break down the problem:

We need to find --cpuname= followed by a value.
The value can be:
Enclosed between $( and ) and can contain any character.
Not enclosed and should not contain an underscore.
Let's write a regex for this:

--cpuname=$([^)]+): This matches --cpuname=$(some_text).
--cpuname=[^_\s]+: This matches --cpuname=someText but not --cpuname=some_text.
Combining these two with an OR | operator should give us the desired regex.

Here's the updated code:

```html
const regex = /--cpuname=(\$\([^)]+\)|[^_\s]+)/;

function checkStringValidity(str) {
  const matches = str.match(regex);
  if (!matches || matches[0] !== matches.input) {
    alert("Underscore not allowed in cpuname value");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Let's test this with your examples:

--cpuname=some_text should be invalid.

--cpuname=$(some_text) should be valid.

--cpuname=$(some_text) -order=abc_def should be valid.

Comment: The above code breaks if i give input string as --cpuname=$(some_text) -abc=def_xyz
Underscore check should happen only for cpuname value.